# Prove that $|z+\frac{1}{z}|\leq2$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $\Big|z^3+\dfrac{1}{z^3}\Big| \leq 2$ then prove that $\Big|z+\dfrac{1}{z}\Big| \le 2$ for a complex number $z$.

**My attempt**:We have:

$|z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}|=|(z+\frac{1}{z})(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}-1)|=|(z+\frac{1}{z})||(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}-1)|$

So for proving that we need to prove $|(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}-1)|>1$ Which is really easy when $z$ is a real number but not when $z$ is complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$(z+1/z )^3=z^3+1/z^3+3(z+1/z) $$